# Why am I getting "Password can't be blank" during user update when not updating the password (Rails 4 with 'has_secure_password')?

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4.0.9 app, using BCrypt 3.1.7 and Clearance 1.4.2 for authentication, I'm getting an error returned when updating a user's info.  Despite not entering a new password or password confirmation, I get the error "Password can't be blank."

I've looked high and low on SO and by Googling, and none of the solutions I find work for me.  Most are for earlier versions of Rails, and may be outdated now, and others don't really fit my exact situation (probably because I'm just doing something boneheaded).

I could remove the password and password_confirmation fields from the edit form, but I *do* want users to be able to update their password while also updating their name or email address, if they feel so inclined.

'has_secure_password' is supposed to only validate on create, yet seems to be validating on update as well.  To troubleshoot the problem, I've disabled my User model's validations for password and password_confirmation, and simply have 'has_secure_password' in place for validation of those parameters.  Can you see why I'm getting the validation error?  Is the Clearance gem overriding has_secure_passwords' default behavior, or influencing validation in any way?

**User model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
include Clearance::User
belongs_to :studio
has_one :public_user

before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
before_create :create_remember_token
after_create :make_public_user

validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true,
                format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
has_secure_password
#   validates :password, length: { minimum: 6, on: :create }
#   validates :password_confirmation, presence: { on: :create }
...
```

**User controller**

```
...
def edit
end

def update
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

private


def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :password_digest)
end
...
```

**Edit form (actually "_fields.html.erb" partial)**

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
```

```
<div class="control-group">
        <%= f.label :name, class: "control-label" %>
<div class="controls">
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :email, class: "control-label" %>
<div class="controls">
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :password, class: "control-label" %>
<div class="controls">
        <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: 'Enter new password if changing' %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation", class: "control-label" %>
    <div class="controls">
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: 'Confirm your new password if changing' %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Parameters passed to controller**

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"name"=>"Ransom Kshlerin III", "email"=>"example-1@samplestudio.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Save changes", "id"=>"4"}
```

**EDIT:**

When I disable 'has_secure_password', I still get the validation error, which leads me to believe Clearance's validations are returning the error.  I think I need to override Clearance's password validation, but only when updating a user.  How should I go about this?

**EDIT 2:**

I'm going to take a different approach altogether.  Instead of allowing password resetting directly on this form, I'll provide a link for resetting the password, which will send the user  an email with a link to reset their password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`has_secure_password` and the Clearance gem each validate password and password confirmation, and I'm not yet skilled enough to override Clearance's validations (over my head).  So I've taken a different approach.  Password and password confirmation will not be included on this edit form.

Instead of allowing password resetting directly on this form, I'll provide a link for resetting the password, which will send the user an email with a link to reset their password.  I suppose the added benefit here is that if a user has managed to log in as another user, they won't be able to reset that user's password unless they've also hacked into the other user's email account.

Answer (score 2):

In the params passed to the controller there's `"password"=>"", "password_confirmation"=>""` present (don't worry about the `[FILTERED]`, that only means Rails won't print the param to the log).

When calling `params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)`  includes `{ password: "", password_confirmation: "", # plus the other keys }`.

When passing this hash to `@user.update_attributes({password: '', password_confirmation: ''})`, the presence validation on the password will kick in and prevent that an empty password is set.

One option to not trying to set an empty password might be deleting the keys from the `user_params` hash unless their values are considered present.

```
def user_params
  user_params = params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) # don't permit `password_digest` here, that database column should not be allowed to be set by the user!

  # Remove the password and password confirmation keys for empty values
  user_params.delete(:password) unless user_params[:password].present?
  user_params.delete(:password_confirmation) unless user_params[:password_confirmation].present?

  user_params
end
```

Comment: And when 'has_secure_password' is commented out in the User model, it's validation routine is not run, correct?  I assume so, which means the Clearance gem's validation routine is returning the error.  I believe I need to either prevent the 'password' and 'password_confirmation' from being passed to the controller when they're left blank, or override Clearance's validation when updating a user record.

Comment: Also, I tried deleting those keys from user_params as you suggest, and get a "stack level too deep" error.  It's Friday, and it's sunny out, and I'm tired of looking at this bug for today.  I'll come back to it on Monday.  :)

Answer (score -1):

Clearance provides a clear (^_^) path to circumvent the password requirement:

```
# Always false. Override this method in your user model to allow for other
# forms of user authentication (username, Facebook, etc).
#
# @return [false]
def password_optional?
  false
end
```

For example, in your User model you can do this:

```
# app/models/user.rb

class User < ApplicationRecord
  include Clearance::User

  def password_optional?
    true
  end
end
```

[Source](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/blob/master/lib/clearance/user.rb#L257)